# C kernel variable data is a sequence of random bytes in long mode x86

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, nasm, osdev

I am trying to write a simple OS just for fun and somewhat practice. I've worked in the real mode before but I decided to move on and try playing with protected mode to have an opportunity to use C rather than plain assembly. I have copied bootloader code that seemed to work and it seems to me that basically all it does is just goes into long mode and of course starts the kernel. So it works fine until you declare a variable in the code, because if you do, QEMU will output what I believe is a chunk of memory translated to ASCII.

So the bootloader code itself:

```
[org 0x7c00]


KERNEL_ADDRESS equ 0x100000

cli

lgdt [gdt_descriptor] 

;Switch to PM
mov eax, cr0 
or eax, 0x1 
mov cr0, eax 

jmp 0x8:init_pm 


[bits 32]

init_pm :
    mov ax, 0x10
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax


call build_page_tables

;Enable PAE
mov eax, cr4                 
or eax, 1 << 5               
mov cr4, eax

;# Optional : Enable global-page mechanism by setting CR0.PGE bit to 1
mov eax, cr4                 
or eax, 1 << 7               
mov cr4, eax

;Load CR3 with PML4 base address
;NB: in some examples online, the address is not offseted as it seems to
;be in the proc datasheet (if you were wondering about this strange thing).
mov eax, 0x1000
mov cr3, eax

;Set LME bit in EFER register (address 0xC0000080)
mov ecx, 0xC0000080     ;operand of 'rdmsr' and 'wrmsr'
rdmsr                   ;read before pr ne pas écraser le contenu
or eax, 1 << 8          ;eax : operand de wrmsr
wrmsr

;Enable paging by setting CR0.PG bit to 1
mov eax, cr0
or eax, (1 << 31)
mov cr0, eax

;Load 64-bit GDT
lgdt [gdt64_descriptor]

;Jump to code segment in 64-bit GDT
jmp 0x8:init_lm


[bits 64]

init_lm:
    mov ax, 0x10
    mov fs, ax          ;other segments are ignored
    mov gs, ax

    mov rbp, 0x90000    ;set up stack
    mov rsp, rbp

    ;Load kernel from disk
    xor ebx, ebx        ;upper 2 bytes above bh in ebx is for cylinder = 0x0
    mov bl, 0x2         ;read from 2nd sectors
    mov bh, 0x0         ;head
    mov ch, 2           ;read 2 sectors
    mov rdi, KERNEL_ADDRESS
    call ata_chs_read


    jmp KERNEL_ADDRESS

    jmp $



;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;[bits 16]
;; http://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_in_x86_RealMode_%28BIOS%29


;load_loader:
    ;;!! il faut rester sur le meme segment, ie <0x10000 (=2**16)
    ;mov bx, LOADER_OFFSET  
    ;mov dh, 1          ;load 1 sector (max allowed by BIOS is 128)
    ;mov dl, 0x80       ;drive number

    ;mov ah, 0x02       ;read function
    ;mov al, dh
    ;mov ch, 0x00       ;cylinder
    ;mov dh, 0x00       ;head
    ;; !! Sector is 1-based, and not 0-based
    ;mov cl, 0x02       ;1st sector to read 
    ;int 0x13
    ;ret


[bits 32]
build_page_tables:
    ;PML4 starts at 0x1000
    ;il faut laisser la place pour tte la page PML4/PDP/PD ie. 0x1000

    ;PML4 @ 0x1000
    mov eax, 0x2000         ;PDP base address            
    or eax, 0b11            ;P and R/W bits
    mov ebx, 0x1000         ;MPL4 base address
    mov [ebx], eax

    ;PDP @ 0x2000; maps 64Go
    mov eax, 0x3000         ;PD base address
    mov ebx, 0x2000         ;PDP physical address   
    mov ecx, 64             ;64 PDP

    build_PDP:
        or eax, 0b11    
        mov [ebx], eax
        add ebx, 0x8
        add eax, 0x1000     ;next PD page base address
        loop build_PDP

    ;PD @ 0x3000 (ends at 0x4000, fits below 0x7c00)
    ; 1 entry maps a 2MB page, the 1st starts at 0x0
    mov eax, 0x0            ;1st page physical base address     
    mov ebx, 0x3000         ;PD physical base address
    mov ecx, 512                        

    build_PD:
        or eax, 0b10000011      ;P + R/W + PS (bit for 2MB page)
        mov [ebx], eax
        add ebx, 0x8
        add eax, 0x200000       ;next 2MB physical page
        loop build_PD

    ;(tables end at 0x4000 => fits before Bios boot sector at 0x7c00)
    ret



;=============================================================================
; ATA read sectors (CHS mode) 
; Max head index is 15, giving 16 possible heads
; Max cylinder index can be a very large number (up to 65535)
; Sector is usually always 1-63, sector 0 reserved, max 255 sectors/track
; If using 63 sectors/track, max disk size = 31.5GB
; If using 255 sectors/track, max disk size = 127.5GB
; See OSDev forum links in bottom of [http://wiki.osdev.org/ATA]
;
; @param EBX The CHS values; 2 bytes, 1 byte (BH), 1 byte (BL) accordingly
; @param CH The number of sectors to read
; @param RDI The address of buffer to put data obtained from disk               
;
; @return None
;=============================================================================
[bits 64]
ata_chs_read:   pushfq
                push rax
                push rbx
                push rcx
                push rdx
                push rdi

                mov rdx,1f6h            ;port to send drive & head numbers
                mov al,bh               ;head index in BH
                and al,00001111b        ;head is only 4 bits long
                or  al,10100000b        ;default 1010b in high nibble
                out dx,al

                mov rdx,1f2h            ;Sector count port
                mov al,ch               ;Read CH sectors
                out dx,al

                mov rdx,1f3h            ;Sector number port
                mov al,bl               ;BL is sector index
                out dx,al

                mov rdx,1f4h            ;Cylinder low port
                mov eax,ebx             ;byte 2 in ebx, just above BH
                mov cl,16
                shr eax,cl              ;shift down to AL
                out dx,al

                mov rdx,1f5h            ;Cylinder high port
                mov eax,ebx             ;byte 3 in ebx, just above byte 2
                mov cl,24
                shr eax,cl              ;shift down to AL
                out dx,al

                mov rdx,1f7h            ;Command port
                mov al,20h              ;Read with retry.
                out dx,al

.still_going:   in al,dx
                test al,8               ;the sector buffer requires servicing.
                jz .still_going         ;until the sector buffer is ready.

                mov rax,512/2           ;to read 256 words = 1 sector
                xor bx,bx
                mov bl,ch               ;read CH sectors
                mul bx
                mov rcx,rax             ;RCX is counter for INSW
                mov rdx,1f0h            ;Data port, in and out
                rep insw                ;in to [RDI]

                pop rdi
                pop rdx
                pop rcx
                pop rbx
                pop rax
                popfq
                ret


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
[bits 16]

GDT:
;null : 
    dd 0x0 
    dd 0x0

;code : 
    dw 0xffff       ;Limit
    dw 0x0          ;Base
    db 0x0          ;Base
    db 10011010b    ;1st flag, Type flag
    db 11001111b    ;2nd flag, Limit
    db 0x0          ;Base

;data : 
    dw 0xffff       
    dw 0x0          
    db 0x0
    db 10010010b 
    db 11001111b 
    db 0x0

gdt_descriptor :
    dw $ - GDT - 1      ;16-bit size
    dd GDT              ;32-bit start address



[bits 32]
;see manual 2, §4.8: most fields are ignored in long mode
GDT64:
;null;
    dq 0x0

;code
    dd 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 0b10011000   
    db 0b00100000
    db 0x0

;data
    dd 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 0b10010000   
    db 0b00000000
    db 0x0

gdt64_descriptor :
    dw $ - GDT64 - 1        ;16-bit size
    dd GDT64                ;32-bit start address


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
[bits 16]
times 510 -($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

I've played around with the code a little bit and simplified it to this state:

```c
void putc(uchar_t __char, uint8_t pos) {    
    uint16_t* vidmemory = (uint16_t*) 0xB8000;
    
    vidmemory[pos] = (uint16_t)__char | (uint16_t)0x0F << 8;
}

const char* hw = "Hello, World!";

void kmain() {
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 14; ++i) {
        putc(hw[i], i);
    }
    for (;;);
    return;
}
```

I had the same problem with the real mode after loading up the kernel, because I forgot to set the Data Segment, but as far as I am concerned segments are almost *obsolete* in the long mode.

## Update

After debugging I, as was expected, found out that values of `hw` were some random bytes from memory. It looks like this:

```
(gdb) x/14bc hw
0x0 <putc>: 83 'S'    -1 '\377' 0 '\000'  -16 '\360'    83 'S'    -1 '\377' 0 '\000'  -16 '\360'
0x8 <putc+8>:   -61 '\303'    -30 '\342'    0 '\000'  -16 '\360'    83 'S'    -1 '\377'
```

I build my image with this script, which also uses "loader.s", but essentially all it does is just calls the kernel itself:

**loader.s**:

```
[bits 64]

extern kmain
global _start

_start:
  call kmain
  
  jmp $
```

And the **build.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

nasm -f bin bootload.s -o boot.bin
nasm -f elf64 loader.s -o loader.o

cc -m64 -masm=intel -c kernel.c -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -g -O2
ld -Ttext 0x100000 -o kernel.elf loader.o kernel.o -e kmain

objcopy -R .note -R .comment -S -O binary kernel.elf kernel.bin

dd if=/dev/zero of=image.bin bs=512 count=2880
dd if=boot.bin of=image.bin conv=notrunc
dd if=kernel.bin of=image.bin conv=notrunc bs=512 seek=1
```

There are probably other problems with my code, but for now I believe it's the matter of the data segment, which I haven't set.

**Screenshot of QEMU**
[image: Kernel output in the upper-left corner]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216362/discussion-on-question-by-its-sl4y3r-c-kernel-variable-data-is-messed-up-in-long).

Comment: Hum , I had similar issues , one where the values printed on the video memory had a wrong offset , that printed garbage : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58633806
And one where my kernel wasn't entirely loaded , due to insufficient number of sector read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62527061
try adding one or two sectors into DH in your load_loader function, and see if it doesn't fix the problem